# I am trying to download Mongoose into my Node.js project via NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

```sh
D:\all Node place\nodejs\demo-app>npm install mongoose
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...~8.4.1","highland":"^'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Srikanth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-09T05_41_01_390Z-debug.log
```

Every time I try to install Node I get this error. My Node and NPM are upgraded to the latest version.

Please can someone help me with this?

Comment: Your package.json may be broken. Can you edit into your question?

Comment: i didn't understand what you said what do you mean package.json broken ???

Comment: There's something wrong with the syntax of your package.json file and npm fails to read it.

Answer (score 0):

might be you have already another package so

```
$ npm uninstall mongoose
```

then

```
$ npm install mongoose
```

try it